# Spyder python 3.9 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, opencv, spyder

```
import os
import cv2
import pickle
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np

train_path = './Train/'

class_list = os.listdir(train_path)


for i in range(len(class_list)):
    image_list = os.listdir(os.path.join(train_path, class_list[i]))
    
    for j in range(len(image_list)):
        image = cv2.imread(os.path.join(train_path, class_list[i], image_list[j]))
        sift = cv2.SIFT_create() 
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        (kp, descs) = sift.detectAndCompute(gray, None)
        
        descs_samples = descs[np.random.randint(descs.shape[0], size=20)]
```

> I am trying to get sift features of 43 diffrent classes of images but for some reason when i try to use the command `descs_samples = descs[np.random.randint(descs.shape[0], size=20)]` function i am getting this eror * AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'*
> My friend was able to runs this code correctly but for some reason i can't.

I tried changing my files loaction and printing images to make sure they were actullay are getting read.I was able to see my images with `print (image)`.

Comment: Hey I'm also able to see the descriptions. Wihch version of OpenCV are you using?

Comment: Hi i am currently using opencv version '4.5.5'.I did a bit more digging and found out for some reason my code gets in to the first class of images without a problem but when it tries to go to the second class and use  the function it gaves me this error.

Comment: Are you sure your file hieararchy is correct?

Train/class1/class1.png , Train/class2/class2.png

I created a mock hieararchy like this and it works perfectly on pycharm, spyder, python 3.8 and 3.9 with OpenCV 4.5.5. Have you tried printing images on second loop too?

Comment: My friend tried the same code with the same dataset as mine and it worked fine for him too. But for some reason after class1 pictures gets read and tries to go into second claass it gets this error.If it would help i could link my dataset.https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/meowmeowmeowmeowmeow/gtsrb-german-traffic-sign

Comment: That would be great if you can share the dataset in minimum reproducable example size.

Comment: I don't know how to do that can you elaborate  on "dataset in minimum reproducable example size" a bit ?

Comment: Just enough images to make the same error occur.

Answer (score 0):

My friend wasn't using the same dataset so i tought there might be something wrong with it.After a bit of debugging i found that i wasn't able to get descropitores from some of the train images.So i isolated them. I lost around %10 of the dataset but now it works great. I am trying to figure out why i couldn't get descriptores from this %10.